# Spring CacheManager vs ETag

Tags: java, spring, caching, etag

I have a Spring (not Boot) application with a successfully configured and used Caching mechanism through the CacheManager that looks like the following:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class CachingConfig {
   @Bean
   public CacheManager cacheManager() {
      SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
      List<Cache> caches = List.of(
         new ConcurrentMapCache("cache_name_1"),
         // ....
      );
      
      cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
      return cacheManager;
   }

}
```

Spring also supports ETags as can be read [here](https://www.baeldung.com/etags-for-rest-with-spring). And it could be configured as follows:

```java
@Bean
public ShallowEtagHeaderFilter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
    return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
}
```

Is there any need for ETags when one has already configured Caching used the first approach above?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different concepts.

**Server side cache**: Calls from different clients with the same parameters can get the same result from server cache.

**Client side cache**: Get once and use ETag to see if anything has changed, no need to get it again if not modified.